# jQuery checkbox matching radiobuttonlist

Tags: jquery

On my pages I have a table with rows that typically look like this:

```
<tr class = "child">
       <td>
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxEyeProblems" runat="server" />

       </td>
       <td align="center">
             <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonListEyeProblems" 
                <asp:ListItem Value="Y">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="N">No</asp:ListItem>
             </asp:RadioButtonList>
       </td>
</tr>
```

What I am trying to do is to disable/enable radiobuttonlist in the same row as the checkbox when you check/uncheck it.

```
$('tr.child input:checkbox').click(function()
{
     //last part of this selector is incorrect, how to correct it here? 
     var rblist = $(this).closest('tr.child').find(':input:radio');

     if ($(this).is(':checked'))
     { 
        //aslo not sure how to clear selection if any from RadioButtonList here
        rblist.attr('disabled', 'disabled');             

     }
     else
     {

         rblist.removeAttr('disabled');

     }

});
```

So, those are the problems I have. I am using ASP.NET 3.5.

Comment: No, you're not using ASP, you're using jQuery with your ASP generated markup. Show us the markup (HTML), not your ASP code.

Comment: This page is a content page under a Master Page, so HTML will have lots of id mangling. This probably gives better idea on what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$("tr.child td input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var chk = $(this);
    //chk.closest("td").next().find("input:radio").attr("disabled",chk.attr("checked"));
    // to remove checked attribute you can use
    chk.closest("td").next().find("input:radio").attr("checked", false).attr("disabled",chk.attr("checked"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am just wondering if chk.closest("td") will work since they are in different "td" elements. And how to clear any rb selection before disabling it?

Comment: even though this exact method doesn't work, for one thing, I need to uncheck only when I uncheck checkbox, but gave me a good idea on how to finish my task